# WSO2IS OAuth/OpenId Connect SSO Setup

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, single-sign-on, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to figure out how to setup my applications for SSO using WSO2 Identity Server. My use case is I have 2 applications secured by OAuth/OpenId Connect using WSO2IS. If I'm logged into application 1, then launching application 2 should automatically log me in. What should the flow be?

Currently, I have created 2 service providers, one for each application. Each service provider inbound authentication configuration is configured using OAuth/OpenId Connect. What else do I need to do?

I've followed https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On. I'm success on being redirected to IS for login and each application is able to obtain access token and JWT. However, I'm being asked to login for each application separately---no automatic login when I access application 2.

Thank you!

WSO2IS output when I login to application 1 then follow by application 2, within the same browser and tab.

<<< Application 1 >>>

[2017-07-27 21:30:17,117] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Validate Client information request for client_id : L7c7Zqf9QpDKjyEtOQ74R__RSy0a and callback_uri http://[hostname]:[8080]/xxxx/
[2017-07-27 21:30:17,124] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Registered App found for the given Client Id : L7c7Zqf9QpDKjyEtOQ74R__RSy0a ,App Name : Application1, Callback URL : http://[hostname]:[8080]/xxxx/
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,506] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Authorization Request received for user : testuser@carbon.super, Client ID : L7c7Zqf9QpDKjyEtOQ74R__RSy0a, Authorization Response Type : code, Requested callback URI : http://[hostname]:[8080]/xxxx/, Requested Scope : email openid profile
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,507] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Added OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext to threadlocal
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,508] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.handlers.CodeResponseTypeHandler} -  Issued Authorization Code to user : testuser@carbon.super, Using the redirect url : http://[hostname]:[8080]/xxxx/, Scope : email openid profile, validity period : 300000
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,510] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Cleared OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,756] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Access Token request received for Client ID L7c7Zqf9QpDKjyEtOQ74R__RSy0a, User ID null, Scope : [] and Grant Type : authorization_code
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,756] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.clientauth.AbstractClientAuthHandler} -  Can authenticate with client ID and Secret. Client ID: L7c7Zqf9QpDKjyEtOQ74R__RSy0a
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,756] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.clientauth.AbstractClientAuthHandler} -  Grant type : authorization_code Strict client validation set to : null
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,757] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Client credentials were fetched from the database.
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,757] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Successfully authenticated the client with client id : L7c7Zqf9QpDKjyEtOQ74R__RSy0a
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,757] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AuthorizationCodeGrantHandler} -  Authorization Code Info was not available in cache for client id : L7c7Zqf9QpDKjyEtOQ74R__RSy0a
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,758] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AuthorizationCodeGrantHandler} -  Found an Authorization Code, Client : L7c7Zqf9QpDKjyEtOQ74R__RSy0a, authorized user : testuser@carbon.super, scope : email openid profile
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,758] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Added OAuthTokenReqMessageContext to threadlocal
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,759] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler} -  Infinite lifetime Access Token c6d1b10e-cd51-379a-9162-4f5228aaa5dc found in cache
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,759] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Cleared OAuthTokenReqMessageContext
[2017-07-27 21:30:30,759] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Access token issued to client Id: L7c7Zqf9QpDKjyEtOQ74R__RSy0a username: testuser@carbon.super and scopes: email openid profile

<<< Application 2 >>>

[2017-07-27 21:30:42,014] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Validate Client information request for client_id : fwM8a593OUxufW2ZaBXYx9f1mREa and callback_uri http://[hostname]:[8090]/xxxx/
[2017-07-27 21:30:42,016] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Registered App found for the given Client Id : fwM8a593OUxufW2ZaBXYx9f1mREa ,App Name : Application2, Callback URL : http://[hostname]:[8090]/xxxx/
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,454] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Authorization Request received for user : testuser@carbon.super, Client ID : fwM8a593OUxufW2ZaBXYx9f1mREa, Authorization Response Type : code, Requested callback URI : http://[hostname]:[8090]/xxxx/, Requested Scope : email openid profile
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,455] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Added OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext to threadlocal
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,457] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.handlers.CodeResponseTypeHandler} -  Issued Authorization Code to user : testuser@carbon.super, Using the redirect url : http://[hostname]:[8090]/xxxx/, Scope : email openid profile, validity period : 300000
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,458] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Cleared OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,739] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Access Token request received for Client ID fwM8a593OUxufW2ZaBXYx9f1mREa, User ID null, Scope : [] and Grant Type : authorization_code
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,739] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.clientauth.AbstractClientAuthHandler} -  Can authenticate with client ID and Secret. Client ID: fwM8a593OUxufW2ZaBXYx9f1mREa
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,739] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.clientauth.AbstractClientAuthHandler} -  Grant type : authorization_code Strict client validation set to : null
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,739] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Client credentials were fetched from the database.
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,739] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Successfully authenticated the client with client id : fwM8a593OUxufW2ZaBXYx9f1mREa
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,739] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AuthorizationCodeGrantHandler} -  Authorization Code Info was not available in cache for client id : fwM8a593OUxufW2ZaBXYx9f1mREa
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,739] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AuthorizationCodeGrantHandler} -  Found an Authorization Code, Client : fwM8a593OUxufW2ZaBXYx9f1mREa, authorized user : testuser@carbon.super, scope : email openid profile
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,740] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Added OAuthTokenReqMessageContext to threadlocal
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,740] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler} -  Infinite lifetime Access Token a01c94d9-c889-3a38-a67e-38a7f0350aa0 found in cache
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,740] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Cleared OAuthTokenReqMessageContext
[2017-07-27 21:30:55,740] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Access token issued to client Id: fwM8a593OUxufW2ZaBXYx9f1mREa username: testuser@carbon.super and scopes: email openid profile

Comment: What about the outbound authenticators configured for each application?

Comment: Are your apps running on localhost domain? Recently chrome has made a change that prevented cookies set for localhost being sent back. So one thing I can suggest is to set your apps in two domains like abc.com and xyz.com and try the same.

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Basic+Client+Profile+with+Playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next step is to setup your client application which will try to authenticate user with WSO2 using OpenID Connect. Follow these steps:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/OpenIDConnect

Once done, create a copy of your application and run on different port and play with SSO and SLO. An example is this:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+OpenID+Connect+Single+Logout

You can learn about the mechanics of how WSO2 IS maintains a SSO session by reading [Enabling Authentication Session Persistence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+Authentication+Session+Persistence).

Comment: Thank you, Agam! I've edited my questions to include the fact that I do have the client applications authenticating and obtaining access token with IS.  Just that after I've logged into application 1, I'm still being asked to login when accessing application 2. Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: That should not happen at the first place. I have few questions though,  In both applications, URL of wso2 is same?? Are cookies enabled in your browser?? Are you trying to open the application in same window ( not using incognito or private browsing for second application??)

Comment: Yes, both applications have the same wso2is url and port number. Initially, cookies were not enabled, but I enabled it. I've tried with Chrome and FF browsers and quit browsers to be sure the setting took effect. I'm not using incognito or private browsing for second application...tried new tab and existing tab.

Comment: Any error on browser console or logs of your  application?? Which application are you using?? Did you check wso2 logs??

Comment: no errors reported on browser console or wso2is system logs. below is the wso2is output where i first login to application 1, then navigate to application 2 within the same browser and tab.  Ooops...log is too long.

Comment: i'm using Django client applications.

Comment: Somehow wso2 is not able to identify that a session exist for that cookie. Or may be your tolen is being expired immediately after login. Could you check this by reloadimg application-1 soon after you open application-2 and see the login page. If the token would have been expired, or the session at wso2 is destroyed, you will see the login page on application one also.

Comment: Last thing you can try is do  the same steps with wso2 playground app as described in the docs of wso2 and see if we get same result.

Comment: reloading application 1 after opening application 2 does NOT display a login page.  yes, I'll try running a second playground application and see what happen.  Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Best of luck and keep update how did you solve the problem :)

Comment: if you have used localhost as domain for the apps, try using a domain name like abc.com and xyz.com for the two apps and try the same. There is a recent improvement done in chrome that prevents cookies being sent from naked domains (domains without a dot)

Comment: turned out there's something wrong with my browsers. Using diff machine and everything work as expected. Thank you!